# Custom AccessDecisionManager in spring security

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

We are integrating our JSF2 application with Spring Security. We have done the basic setup and its working fine. However we need to implement a custom access decision manager to filter the requests.
For example if user with user privileges try to access a page dedicated to admin, in this case we need to check first whether the user is logged in or not , if logged in get his authorities. I have written a access decision manager and i am still in the process of enhancing it. But when i deploy i am getting below error.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AccessDecisionManager does not support secure object class: class org.springframework.security.web.FilterInvocation

Any idea what is the reason for the same.

below is sample from my security-config.xml

        disable-url-rewriting="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">

Comment: I followed the below link and solved the issue.https://bitsofinfo.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/accessdecisionmanager-does-not-support-secure-object-class/ . I changed the return type of supports() method to true. Any idea how it works?